# Regex not matching as expected

Tags: ruby, regex, .htaccess, templates

I need to edit areas of a template and produce a `.htaccess` file. Here's a portion of the template for the `.htaccess` file. The `[NPAC_TMP:~core_dir]` are the pieces that get replaced:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^[NPAC_TMP:~core_dir]/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ [NPAC_TMP:~core_dir]/$1
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?localhost:8888$
RewriteRule ^(/)?$ [NPAC_TMP:~core_dir]/index.php [L] ###DEFECTIVE LINE
```

Ruby Script:

```
template_tag = line.match(/\[NPAC_TMP:~(.*)\]/).to_s
param        = template_tag.split("~")[1][0..-2]

if(param == "core_dir")
  line[template_tag]= CONFIG[:core_dir]
  temp_file.puts line
end
```

When the script is run, all of them get replaced properly except the last one:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^core/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ core/$1
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?localhost:8888$
RewriteRule ^(/)?$ [NPAC_TMP:~core_dir]/index.php [L] ###DEFECTIVE LINE
```

This isn't the only template file this method runs in, and in every other file, it works properly where all the items get replaced.

For troubleshooting purposes, I copied the `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^[NPAC_TMP:~core_dir]/"` and put it directly below the defective line. This added item updated correctly, but the one above it still did not.

I then placed a copy of the defective line directly below it as well and received two defective lines, which leads me to believe its something in the way that this full string is structured that is throwing the REGEX off: `RewriteRule ^(/)?$ [NPAC_TMP:~core_dir]/index.php [L]`

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Also if you have suggestions on how to shorten up or improve the Ruby portion of the script I'm all ears.

Comment: If you want what comes between the `~` and the `]`, you can just use `line.match(/../)[1]` instead of `.to_s`, to get what is between the parentheses in your regex -- the first "group" (`String#match` actually returns a [MatchData](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/MatchData.html) object which gives you all of the groups of your match).  Then you don't have to mess around with `split` and string splicing stuff.

Comment: np :)  I try to avoid dealing with strings at that low a level as much as possible and I think in most languages where you don't have to, it's a general good practice.  it's easier to maintain and easier to understand for other readers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `.*` in your regex `\[NPAC_TMP:~(.*)\]` is greedy (it matches as much as it can), so it matches

```
[NPAC_TMP:~core_dir]/index.php [L]
```

which gives you the group

```
core_dir]/index.php [L
```

see http://rubular.com/r/NbZxd5prdT

You should use `[^]]*` (or `[^]]+` instead of `.*`

see http://rubular.com/r/h0YcyWfvgu

Next time if you run into regex problems a good way to go is to print/trace out your matches so you can see what exactly you're matching.

I also always just "develop"/write my regexes in [**rubular**](http://rubular.com/) to make sure they work out as I expect.

Comment: Improvement on the answer I found. Just to increase my knowledge would there be a case where using the `[^]]*` would be more accurate then using the `[^]]`? Or faster / better ect?

Comment: (I meant to say `[^]]+`) I'm not sure which is better performance wise, it just seems like you aren't really expecting the `[]` case to match.

Comment: Also I don't see any reason why you couldn't just modify your original regex to include `~core_dir` and just do a simple `String#gsub`

Comment: There's a lot more to the function then just this piece.`~core_dir` is one of many params. Glad at least one failed so now I know better :)

Answer (score 2):

Forgot to make the group not-greedy:

```
template_tag = line.match(/\[NPAC_TMP:~(.*)\]/).to_s
```

should be:

```
template_tag = line.match(/\[NPAC_TMP:~(.*?)\]/).to_s
```

Solved the issue, matches all cases now.

Comment: The term isn't "lazy", it's "not-greedy".